# Decrementing field in Postgresql doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm playing with incrementing a field in Postgresql.
Suppose I have a table `questions` and a BIGINT field called `votes` which already has the value of 100000000.

Now I want to decrement it like this:

```
UPDATE questions SET votes=votes-31500000 WHERE id = 1;
```

Unfortunately, the end result is for some reason value `-21500000` in this field.
If, however I first get the field value and then calculate the necessary decremented value in my code and not in an SQL query, then the value is correctly calculated to be `68500000`, which I can then set using this query:

```
UPDATE questions SET votes=#{calculated_value} WHERE id = 1;
```

Needless to say, the latter way is not acceptable due to concurrency issues. Thus, my question is: why is Postgresql behaving this way and how do I correctly decrement the value using an SQL query?

Comment: Your query works for me... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e82c/1

Comment: Post the result of `select votes, votes - 31500000 from questions where id = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you are setting the initial value to:

```
10,000,000
```

instead of

```
100,000,000
```

(commas added for clarity)

That is the simplest explanation of why your decrement of 31,500,000 would produce the negative value.

Comment: Yep, this is probably the case, thanks for pointing out. Need to investigate this.